# Find if codepoint is upper case in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I need to detect if a codepoint is an upper case letter in Elixir. I have tried checking if it's value is in the range `65..90` but this fails on non-latin upper case letters. I have also tried checking if

`String.upcase(cp) == cp`

however this fails on non-letters (ie numbers, punctuation).

I really don't want to go through the entirety of unicode and create a list of upper case codepoints, is there a built in function for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `\p{Lu}` Unicode character property regex escape sequence to match any uppercase letter:

```
iex(1)> "a" =~ ~r/^\p{Lu}$/u
false
iex(2)> "A" =~ ~r/^\p{Lu}$/u
true
iex(3)> "π" =~ ~r/^\p{Lu}$/u
false
iex(4)> "Π" =~ ~r/^\p{Lu}$/u
true
iex(5)> "!" =~ ~r/^\p{Lu}$/u
false
```

Make sure you pass the `u` flag to turn on Unicode matching in the regex.

You can find more information about the supported properties on [this](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) page. Search for the heading "Unicode character properties" on the page.

Comment: Do note that Regular Expressions are very slow, when compared to e.g. pattern matching. There is [a proposal to add functionality like this to the Elixir standard library](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-core/DU-_euhvVk0), although it might instead be added to a separate Hex package as the Unicode library is already very big.

Comment: This fails on multiline strings (`"A\na"` will be matched as uppercased, though it unlikely should be.) Please correct it to use `\A` and `\z` terminators, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use something like this:

```
<< *CODEPOINT* :: utf8 >> != String.downcase(<< *CODEPOINT* :: utf8 >>)
```

there is maybe a better way but that's the start.

Comment: is there a clause guard safe way to determine character case?