# How to find out if whole string is upper case in Elixir?

Tags: regex, string, elixir, uppercase

How can I find out whether a whole string is uppercase in Elixir?

I've found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966980). But it only addresses one letter at a time not the whole string.

Comment: Regardless of the environment, normally you put the whole string in uppercase and see if they match.

Comment: Believe this would work too:

str_lower = "hello world"
String.equivalent?(str_lower, String.upcase(str_lower))
<false>

str_title = "Hello World"
String.equivalent?(str_title, String.upcase(str_title))
<false>
    
str_upper = "HELLO WORLD"
String.equivalent?(str_upper, String.upcase(str_upper))
<true>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Regex:

```
iex> str = "Hello World"
iex> str =~ ~r(^[^a-z]*$)
false

iex> str = "HELLO WORLD"
iex> str =~ ~r(^[^a-z]*$)
true
```

Comment: Note that this will only work for ASCII letters. `"π" =~ ~r(^[^a-z]*$) #=> true` but `π` is lowercase of `Π`.

Comment: this solved it for me, thanx!

Answer (score 27):

You can convert the string to upper case and check if it equals the original string:

```
iex(1)> upcase? = fn x -> x == String.upcase(x) end
#Function<6.99386804/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>    
iex(2)> upcase?.("foo")
false
iex(3)> upcase?.("FOO")
true
iex(4)> upcase?.("π")
false
iex(5)> upcase?.("Π")
true
```

Comment: `upcase? = & &1 == String.upcase(&1)`

Comment: This answer **must** be accepted as the correct one.

Comment: Nice use of a lambda @mudasobwa

Comment: I'm curious why you used the lambda for this. Not criticizing, just want to understand your reasoning. I've done this as `defp upcase?(input), do: input == String.upcase(input)` and wonder what the gain is with the lambda.