# Numbers interpreted as upcase chars

Tags: algorithm, elixir

I'm following an exercice on exercism.io

Pretty new in the Elixir community and language, I'm doing the Elixir path to train.
Anyway, I'm hitting a brickwall and I can't understand why.

The exercice is the following :

> Bob is a lackadaisical teenager. In conversation, his responses are very limited.
>
> Bob answers 'Sure.' if you ask him a question.
>
> He answers 'Whoa, chill out!' if you yell at him.
>
> He answers 'Calm down, I know what I'm doing!' if you yell a question at him.
>
> He says 'Fine. Be that way!' if you address him without actually saying anything.
>
> He answers 'Whatever.' to anything else.
>
> Bob's conversational partner is a purist when it comes to written communication and always follows normal rules regarding sentence punctuation in English.

So my code looks like this :

```
defmodule Bob do
   def hey(input) do
     input = String.trim(input)
     is_empty? = &(String.length(&1) == 0)
     is_upcase? = &(&1 == String.upcase(&1))
     is_question? = &(String.ends_with?(&1, "?"))
     cond do
       is_question?.(input) && is_upcase?.(input) ->
         "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!"
       is_question?.(input) ->
         "Sure."
       is_empty?.(input) ->
         "Fine. Be that way!"
       is_upcase?.(input) == true ->
         "Whoa, chill out!"
       true ->
         "Whatever."
     end
   end
end
```

To verify if the exercice is correct, we've got a test suite which is pretty good.
Two tests doesn't pass :

```
  1) test only numbers (BobTest)
     bob_test.exs:71
     Assertion with == failed
     code:  assert Bob.hey("1, 2, 3") == "Whatever."
     left:  "Whoa, chill out!"
     right: "Whatever."
     stacktrace:
       bob_test.exs:72: (test)

......

  2) test question with numbers (BobTest)
     bob_test.exs:76
     Assertion with == failed
     code:  assert Bob.hey("4?") == "Sure."
     left:  "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!"
     right: "Sure."
     stacktrace:
       bob_test.exs:77: (test)

.......

Finished in 0.09 seconds (0.08s on load, 0.01s on tests)
15 tests, 2 failures

Randomized with seed 683339
```

So my questions is the following : Why are numbers interpreted as upcase letters even if I pass it through `String.downcase("foo")` ?

Comment: Aren't you just checking if passing the input through `upcase` doesn't change the input in `is_upcase? = &(&1 == String.upcase(&1))`? If so, it seems that that is not a  sufficient condition for detecting shouting because `upcase` also doesn't change numbers.

Comment: Validate that the string does indeed contain alphabetic characters `is_upcase? = &(&1 == String.upcase(&1))` → `is_upcase? = &(&1 == String.upcase(&1) && Regex.match?(~r/\p{L}/, &1))`. `\p{L}` matcher is used to match any letter in any language, like `"Я"` or `"Ö"`.

Comment: Thanks both of you !
@AlekseiMatiushkin that's the right solution ! I've know a bit about regex but as much as I would. Didn't know the \p.
So yeah, it's matching all letters and lowers them. 
I was taking the problem in an appropriate angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String.upcase/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#upcase/2) returns a string with the letters converted to upper-case. There is no concept of upper and lower-case for numbers.

Your code `&1 == String.upcase(&1)` is comparing a string to an upper-case version of itself. In the case of a string containing no letters, those are identical. For example `"1" == String.upcase("1")`.

The bug is that your `is_upcase?` function isn't actually checking if the string contains uppercase characters. As mentioned in the comments and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36967499/1225617) you can add a regular expression to check that the string does actually contain an upper-case character.

By the way, the convention when using functions that end with a `?` is not to prefix them with `is_`. So your function would be better named `upcase?`.

```elixir
upcase? = &(&1 == String.upcase(&1) && String.match?(&1, ~r/\p{Lu}/u))
```

It's better to explicitly check for upper-case characters, because there are over 100,000 unicode "letters", but less than 2,000 that are considered upper-case (case-agnostic example for your tests: `"聞いてる?"`).

Comment: Yes I was taking the problem with an inappropriate angle. So I've decided to check if the equivalent of the input at downcase is not equal to the input in upcase rather than using a Regex. 

I've saw that beggining a function with is_ prefered for guard clauses so I've updated it. Thanks for your answer. It's very helpful !

Comment: "input at downcase is not equal to the input in upcase" - that will also match whispering, i.e. strings that contain lowercase letters but no uppercase letters. You're right about `is_` for guards, but your functions are not guards. [Guards](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/guards.html) can only use a small subset of functions, or macros that use those functions, and things like checking every character in a string and running regular expressions are not permitted.

Comment: `~r/\p{Lu}/u` matcher makes `&1 == String.upcase(&1)` check redundant doesn’t it?

Comment: No, because the string could also contain non-uppercase characters. Both conditions could be replaced by a "only non-letters and non-lowercase letters" regex. Although both this regex and the answer are assuming caseless letters constitute SHOUTING.

Comment: Sorry, should have said "don't constitute".